# Live cd boot malfunction

Tags: boot

Attempting to run 16.04 Live cd. Each boot errors with Frenquecy out of range.
I cannot get a boot with enter, ctlF1 esc or any other key combo. I have struggling with Ubuntu for over  a week. How do I get it to work where it is at least as dependable as Windoes????
Thanks Stan 
Correction: FREQENCY SHOULD BE INPUT SIGNAL

Answer (score 1):

When you boot the Ubuntu Live DVD, you should see a row of special function keys at the bottom of your screen. The last one, `F6` will bring up a few options. Choose `nomodeset` and see if that allows you to boot without the frequency out of range errors. Cheers, Al